# The location property is required for this definition

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-hdinsight, azure-logic-apps

While I deploying two HDInsight clusters (Hadoop,HBase) in Azure using Template Deployment with Logic App flow I am getting the following error at the time of creating the Hadoop Cluster but Hbase cluster is created without any issues.

```
Error:
At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-debug for usage details. (Code: DeploymentFailed)

Error details
The location property is required for this definition.
```

I tried with Azure Function App's HTTP Trigger as well in Logic App, but I got the same error as above.

Any help will much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the location property to your arm template for the Hadoop cluster resource.

Here's a link to HDInsight ARM documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-hadoop-create-linux-clusters-arm-templates

```
{
   ...
   "location": "West US",
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Matt Mason - MSFT  , i added as per your comments and its just worked fine.